# ASP.NET Identity - Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity.

I can issue tokens easily but now I want to add additional security requiring my clients to send the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

So I am overriding the  `OAuthAutorizationProvider`

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId;
        string clientSecret;
        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
        {
            //My code here
        }

        context.Validated();
    }
```

The issue is that I cannot get the clientId and the ClientSecret from the `TryGetBasicCredentials` it's always `false` the result.

Maybe I am missing something...

```
POST http://localhost:1323/token

Host: localhost:1673
Content-Length: 102
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=foo&password=123456&client_id=123&client_secret=guess
```

Comment: So what **is** happening?

Comment: The `else` in your code atleast needs an if statement to begin with...

Comment: Sorry the code was not correctly copy pasted.

Comment: @ArtOfCode The TryGetBasicCredentials is not retrieving the ClientId and ClientSecret provided on the request.

Comment: @PeterJoseph How are we meant to debug `// my code here`?? Add your code.

Comment: @ArtOfCode but the code inside does not make any difference here, because the issue happens on the ``TryGetBasicCredentials``.

Comment: @PeterJoseph Then add `TryGetBasicCredentials`. Or tell us how it's supposed to work. Or exactly what actually happens. Or something...

Comment: TryGetBasicCredentials is from .NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthvalidateclientauthenticationcontext.trygetbasiccredentials%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: @PeterJoseph TryGetBasicCredential get HTTP Basic Auth credentials from request header (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#page-5).
So, you should parste your string to get clientId and clientSecret

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to you sending the clientID in the Form.

If you use TryGetFormCredentials instead of TryGetBasicCredentials, you will get your result.

However is you want to use TryGetBasicCredentials send your clientID in the request header.
Seee
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side